# What is 'Context' in android?

Tags: android, android-context

Can any one tell me about **Context**"? I know we need to use context for UI modification.

Can any one  brief me what it is about please? I have seen like `getApplicationContext()` , `getBaseContext()` ? What is the difference between them ?

Comment: Have you tried getting through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html ? It's written really nice.